# Telegram bot in Python with webhook. Deploying on server with Digitalocean droplet

Tags: python, flask, server, webhooks, digital-ocean

I want to understand how recently created webhook works. Having some code in python3 I was able to see that the webhook was set but my telegram bot doesn't respond to commands /start,'any text'. Only when I refresh URL for which I created webhook it is possible to see that the GET method works.

**Bot configuration .py file:**

```
import logging
import time
import flask
import telebot


API_TOKEN = 'My Token from bot father'

WEBHOOK_HOST = 'My domain name bot.vpsprovider.com'
WEBHOOK_PORT = 88  # 443, 80, 88 or 8443 (port need to be 'open')
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = '0.0.0.0'  # In some VPS you may need to put here the IP addr

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = '/path/to/fullchain.pem'  # Path to the ssl certificate
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = '/path/to/privkey.pem'  # Path to the ssl private key


WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = 'https://{var1}:{var2}'.format(var1=WEBHOOK_HOST, var2=WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = '/{var3}/'.format(var3 = API_TOKEN)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

app = flask.Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'HEAD'])
def index():
    return ''



@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)



@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message,
                 ("Hi there, I am EchoBot.\n"
                  "I am here to echo your kind words back to you."))



@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)



bot.remove_webhook()

time.sleep(0.1)

# Set webhook
logging.info('set webhook')
bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,
                certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))
logging.info('webhook set')

# Start flask server
app.run(host=WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
        port=WEBHOOK_PORT,
        ssl_context=(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV),
        debug=True
        )
```

This is what I have put inside server block configuration file:
**Nginx server configuration file within sites-enabled:**

```
#Bot config.
server {

    root /path/to/serverblock/bot;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name bot.vpsprovider.com; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 405 =200 $uri;

    listen [::]:88 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 88 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/path/to/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/path/to/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/path/to/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/path/to/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Picture with: [Debug process on server's console. Not sure why does it say running on https://my actual IP and not the DNS which I specified when registering certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYcxJ.png)

It is worth mentioning that in order to obtain a certificate I used Certbot's command -- **sudo certbot --nginx -d bot.vpsprovider.com**, as you can see I did not specify IP address but the domain name. However, when I run this script on server it says that:

> Running on https://20.115.90.11:88

I expect it to be running on https://bot.vpsprovider.com instead. Is there something wrong with my nginx server file configuration or the way I requested certificate or should I look elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

#Bot config.
server {

```
root /path/to/serverblock/bot;
index index.html index.htm;
server_name bot.vpsprovider.com; # managed by Certbot

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
error_page 405 =200 $uri;

listen [::]:88 ssl; # managed by Certbot
listen 88 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/path/to/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/path/to/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/path/to/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/path/to/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

}

Comment: Could you clarify what about this config?